# How to Make twilio voice call from IOS using in C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twilio

I  have developed a small application using twilio api to make call to any phone number from my twilio number. After dialing call is establishing and a specific audio clip is playing in mobile end. But I am not getting any real voice in any side of the call. Please help me or give me some information regarding how can i get voice in voice call using twilio api. Can anyone tell me the full sceneriyo that how can i make a call from IOS app to any phone numebr. Thanks, Amit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

To [make calls from an iOS application you need the Twilio Programmable Voice SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/voip-sdk). There is a [quickstart application](https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-swift#quickstart) you can run and look at to see how it all fits together. Check out the [rest of the documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/voip-sdk/ios) for more information.

Comment: Cool! If it helped, could you also mark the answer as correct so that others can see it was useful? Thanks!